# Can I use my laptop without an internal fan, but tape a fan from another laptop to the exhaust vent?

Tags: laptop, fan

Can I use a fan from another laptop taped to the exhaust vent to compensate for the removed fan in my laptop? My laptop is HP Elitebook 8440p.

Comment: No; The heatsink is required for your cpu

Comment: "to compensate for the removed fan in my laptop" You need to replace the fan on the heatsink with a like-for-like. An external fan is not going to be viable, you need airflow over the heatsink.

Comment: Even so, it'll over heat very quickly. This is just a bad idea, walk away.

Comment: Depends. Laptop manufacturers spend a lot of money designing systems to remove heat quickly, they don't design laptops to have a desk fan strapped to the side.

Comment: @s7382 Blow over the heatsink in an efficient manner, no. Laptops aren't hermetically sealed, so all blowing air through the exhaust vent is going to do is inefficiently push turbulent air into the laptop casing, with only a minute percentage of airflow cooling the heat pipes, and worse, it's going to heat up other motherboard components by forcing hot air heated by the heat pipes into the laptop, essentially acting as a forced-air space heater _(it's likely the CPU would thermal shutdown within 30min)_. The air going out of the intake vents would be passive with minimal CFM exiting it.

Comment: Aren't all these answers all moot to begin with, since the CPU temperature readout header pin comes from the fan itself?  If you can't override the temp sensor from BIOS (I know on desktops you can on some mobos, but I've never seen this as an available configuration option on *any* notebook), then it won't boot to begin with, correct?

Answer (score 6):

This question basically comes down to the following question:

> How does a CPU cooler cool the CPU?

The CPU generates heat, and lots of it. Temperatures go well over 150 degrees Celcius and the materials used to construct the CPU cannot handle these temperatures. The CPU would explode.

To combat this, the motherboard has failsafe build-in to monitor the temperature and perform action to ensure that the CPU stays alive. In some computers/laptops the computer is shutdown entirely, in other (mostly newer laptops), the motherboard slows the CPU down in order to make it generate less heat and only if that is unsuccesful, shutdown the computer.

As the CPU generates heat, the heat needs to be moved away as quickly as possible. Using cooling paste and a heatsink, the heat is transferred away from the CPU. If this was all there was to it, the heatsink itself would warm up quickly and the CPU would not be able to release enough heat.

In order to cool the heatsink as best as possible, fans are as close to the heatsink as possible to cool the heatsink down.

In a laptop this is the best you can do in the closed space.

You ask:

> Can I use a fan from another laptop taped to the exhaust vent to compensate for the removed fan in my laptop?

I don't think this is going to work. The exhaust vent and the heatsink are too far apart. The heatsink would not lose enough heat to allow the CPU to cool down and the most likely result is going to be that you will get a lot of Blue Screen of Death errors regularly.

If you cannot replace the heatpipe/cooler combo, it is better to replace the entire laptop.

Answer (score 0):

For my experience I am using an laptop with no fan in it. BUT THE CONDITION i gave are:-

1. Its kept on a surfce which absorb the heat of my laptop case thus the heat is slowly taken out from laptop.
2. There is a cooler in side of the laptop as to cool the upper part of case. And also sometimes when the cooler is in high power then it rotates the fan at very slow speed. Thus making it more cool.

But this all will take a lot of money than a essential  internal fan.

So , my advice is too replace the internal fan or give it a second life as a desktop you can also give it case through cardboard if it is for simple web browsing!!!

Conclusion : Just Repair the internal fan as the heat is from the internal components.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).